# Oracle Toplink 11g with Spring 2.5.6 Transaction Manager

Tags: spring, weblogic-10.x, spring-transactions, toplink, transactionmanager

We are migrating from OC4J to Weblogic.
But we want to keep using Toplink in Weblogic with Spring 2.5.6.

In my case, I want to join both Toplink Transaction with my own Transaction within one transaction manager.
Is it possible to work Oracle Toplink 11g with Spring 2.5.6?
Im not sure Spring 2.5.6 can use Oracle Toplink 11g or not

Comment: Spring 2.5 still has toplink support, I don't really get your question regarding transactions. There is the `ToplinkTransactionManager` which you should use to declaratively manage your transactions. All this is explained in the reference guide... See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/reference/orm.html#orm-toplink

Comment: Yes. But it cant support Oracle Toplink 11g. It only support Toplink 10g